# Python script that generates random csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python script that given some configuration, generates a random [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file that can be used for testing purposes.

I want to know if it adheres to the best Python and coding practices. It works for cases where I need upwards of 10K+ rows fast enough for my requirements, so I am not too worried about performance although
inputs on performance are also appreciated.

**Input:**

1. Schema: as a dict, information about each column name, data type and some other constraints (like fixed length/in a range/ from a given list)
2. Number of rows
3. Name of the output CSV file

**Script:**

```
import random as rnd
import csv
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

# csv creator, creates a csv files with a given config
roundPrecision = 3


class BoundType(ABC):
    def __init__(self, dtype, params):
        self.dType = dtype
        self.params = params

    @abstractmethod
    def generate(self):
        pass


class FixedLength(BoundType):
    # params is length
    def generate(self):
        length = self.params.get("len", 1)
        if self.dType == "int":
            return rnd.randint(10 ** (length - 1), 10 ** length - 1)
        elif self.dType == "float":
            return FixedLength("int", self.params).generate() + round(rnd.random(), roundPrecision)
        elif self.dType == "string":
            alphabet = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
            word = [rnd.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(length)]
            return ''.join(word)
        else:
            return None


class FixedRange(BoundType):
    # params is range
    def generate(self):
        lo, hi = (self.params.get("lohi"))
        if self.dType == "int":
            return rnd.randint(lo, hi)
        elif self.dType == "float":
            return round(rnd.uniform(lo, hi), roundPrecision)
        else:
            return None


class FromPossibleValues(BoundType):
    # params is a list
    def generate(self):
        possibleval = self.params.get("set", set())
        return rnd.choice(possibleval)


def createcsv(rows, filename, schema):
    with open(f'./output/{filename}.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(schema.keys())
        for _ in range(rows):
            writer.writerow([x.generate() for x in schema.values()])
```

**Test:**

```
from csvGen.csvGenerator import FixedLength, FixedRange, FromPossibleValues, createcsv

schema = {
    "col1": FixedLength("int", {"len": 5}),
    "col2": FixedLength("float", {"len": 5}),
    "col3": FixedLength("string", {"len": 5}),
    "col4": FixedRange("int", {"lohi": (10, 15)}),
    "col5": FixedRange("float", {"lohi": (5.5, 6.7)}),
    "col6": FromPossibleValues("int", {"set": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}),
    "col7": FromPossibleValues("int", {"set": [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]}),
    "col8": FromPossibleValues("int", {"set": ["A", "AB"]})
}

rows = 10
fileName = "eightVals"
createcsv(rows, fileName, schema)
```

**This is what the output looks like for the given test :**

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51685 | 71830.471 | PAXBK | 12 | 6.192 | 1 | 2.2 | AB |
| 60384 | 42341.991 | RHNUK | 11 | 6.037 | 1 | 1.1 | AB |
| 73505 | 30997.171 | DVOGT | 10 | 6.69 | 5 | 2.2 | A |
| 60528 | 85072.731 | FWWXW | 10 | 5.761 | 1 | 2.2 | A |
| 23048 | 65401.245 | EVPUX | 13 | 6.474 | 4 | 1.1 | AB |
| 74748 | 66969.774 | PEULP | 15 | 6.546 | 3 | 2.2 | AB |
| 88763 | 34749.184 | VOAUO | 10 | 6.402 | 4 | 2.2 | AB |
| 77351 | 44566.163 | JOBQF | 13 | 5.683 | 1 | 2.2 | AB |
| 50820 | 73002.154 | EACZT | 15 | 5.711 | 1 | 1.1 | AB |
| 53037 | 89225.572 | YTLBI | 13 | 6.328 | 1 | 2.2 | AB |

Comment: @Peter, your edit was mostly good, but please don't change the code comments for grammar/spelling, as that's an aspect of review.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems overbuilt, and would also be more tersely expressed with Numpy/Pandas. Additionally, your manual loops - whereas you're satisfied with current performance - will be faster in vectorised form.

This program can be as simple as

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_uppercase
from numpy.random import default_rng

round_precision = 3
nrows = 10
rand = default_rng()
array_3 = rand.choice(tuple(ascii_uppercase), size=(nrows, 5))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': rand.integers(low=1e4, high=1e5, size=nrows),
    'col2': rand.uniform(low=1e4, high=1e5, size=nrows).round(decimals=round_precision),
    'col3': pd.DataFrame(array_3).agg(''.join, axis=1),
    'col4': rand.integers(low=10, high=16, size=nrows),
    'col5': rand.uniform(low=5.5, high=6.7, size=nrows).round(decimals=round_precision),
    'col6': rand.integers(low=1, high=6, size=nrows),
    'col7': rand.choice(np.linspace(start=1.1, stop=3.3, num=3), size=nrows),
    'col8': rand.choice(('A', 'AB'), size=nrows),
})
df.to_csv('eightVals.csv', index=None)
```

with output

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
90510,54337.357,TITJJ,12,6.254,2,2.2,A
82827,10498.364,MLZFY,11,5.881,5,2.2,A
81292,95873.98,UOHVL,14,5.931,2,1.1,AB
44278,69859.781,RGQVO,11,6.492,2,2.2,AB
26424,18106.356,XPCYV,15,6.176,5,2.2,AB
12324,52143.779,VUEWA,15,5.959,2,3.3,A
38774,34881.201,URXXL,15,6.545,2,2.2,AB
25801,31699.204,XEWGS,14,6.427,3,3.3,A
59555,98153.322,WYGBV,11,6.062,1,2.2,A
44449,86569.519,MDNXN,15,6.229,1,3.3,A
```

If this needs to be reusable (and I'm not entirely convinced that it is, given what you've shown), you can adapt the above to utility functions. I don't know that classes are necessary.

Comment: Storing the config separately makes a lot of sense in data pipelines IMHO. Classes don't seem necessary just for that indeed though.

Answer (score 9):

I like how you started designing with `generate` method as interface for your generators. I like how you define your schema. I like also how the final loop and code works.

Really can't agree with the way you implemented your `generate` methods. First it was incredibly confusing and it took me unnecessarily too long to figure out, what are these classes about. To be more specific:

- Why passing params as dict? Why not pass named parameters and make them instance variables? It would make code much more readable and easier to use. Only reason I can think about is that you could instantiate all those classes with same type of parameters (but you don't need to do that).
- That big `if` in your `generate` method is code smell. Each of those if branches should be it's own class with it's own `generate` implementation.
- Names `FixedLength` and `FromPossibleValues` can be better.

Some possibilities examples how to implement your classes better (imho):

```
class FixedLengthIntGenerator(BoundType):
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def generate(self):
        length = self.length
            return rnd.randint(10 ** (length - 1), 10 ** length - 1)


# TODO: other classes for string, float, range ...

class FromPresetChoicesGenerator(BoundType):
    def __init__(self, choices):
        self.choices = choices

    def generate(self):
       return rnd.choice(self.choices)
```

Yes it is more verbose, but it is more readable, extensible, different implementations are not so bound. Also it's not necessary to pass this "dType" anymore. Instead, you choose what implementation to use.

Comment: If you use a class having two methods, one of which is `__init__`, you should be using a function instead. Additionally using inheritance without a single call to `super()` or any of the parent class' features, is a big no no for me.